# What is the C# equivalent for &H2?

Tags: c#, vb.net

can someone please advise what is the c# equivelant for this:

&H2

here's the line of code from VB:

```
direntEnableEntry.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = intVal And Not &H2
```

here's the converted code:

```
   direntEnableEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = (intVal & !=0x2);
```

Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int'

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the `&H2` but with the `(intVal & !=0x2)` expression. One of those operators doesn't belong.

Comment: Just try changing `(intVal & !=0x2)` to `(intVal != 0x2)`!

Comment: @cramopy: Your suggestion appears to be random without any regard for the original VB code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`intVal And Not &H2` is equivalent to the following C#:

```
intVal & ~0x2
```

You got the `0x2` hex literal translated correctly, but `Not` in VB.NET (when applied to a numeric value) corresponds to the bitwise `~` operator, not `!=` (which in VB is `<>`, if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 4):

In C#, the `0x` prefix denotes hexadecimal notation. So the equivalent of VB's `&H2` is `0x2`.

The line in question performs a bitwise NOT on this value, and then does a bitwise AND between the result and `intVal`. In C#, `~` is the bitwise NOT operator. So this line would look something like the following in C#:

```
direntEnableEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = (intVal & ~0x2);
```

Note that `!` (and `!=`) is a logical NOT, which differs from a bitwise NOT.